# How to get only the RGB values from extcolor

Tags: python, regex, python-imaging-library, extcolors

I am using the `extcolor` library to get the colours in a given image. The return is either a list of tuple or a list of lists of tuples.  This is an output for 5 input images in a list.

```
color_list = [
     [((0, 113, 197), 25727)],
     [((4, 7, 7), 17739)],
     [((66, 133, 244), 6567), ((234, 67, 53), 4112), ((251, 188, 5), 2045), ((52, 168, 83), 1232), ((0, 255, 255), 32), ((255, 128, 0), 14), ((255, 255, 0), 9)],
     [((209, 54, 57), 39025), ((255, 255, 255), 10311), ((226, 130, 132), 204), ((0, 0, 0), 32)]
 ]
```

The values `(a, b, c)` are the RGB values I am interested in. How do I only extract those ones? The first image has only one RGB output while the 3rd one has five.

This is my code that just returns the color values in each image:

```
for logo in games:
    rand1, rand2, rand3 = (random.randint(0, 255),
                           random.randint(0, 255),
                           random.randint(0, 255))

    png = Image.open(logo).convert('RGBA')
    colors = extcolors.extract_from_path(logo)

    background = Image.new('RGBA', png.size, (rand1, rand2, rand3))

    alpha_composite = Image.alpha_composite(background, png)
    print(colors)
```

Comment: What are the expected results for the example input images? Which regex have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried regex yet. Also, what do you mean by expected results? I just want to take the tuples out of the input..

Comment: I don't see list of lists of tuples - in all exaples I see `list of tuples`. So in all exaples you could use the same `list comprehension` or normal `for`-loop to get expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all examples I see only `list of tuples` so you can use the same simple `for`-loop for examples to extract data.

```
color_list = [
     [((0, 113, 197), 25727)],
     [((4, 7, 7), 17739)],
     [((66, 133, 244), 6567), ((234, 67, 53), 4112), ((251, 188, 5), 2045), ((52, 168, 83), 1232), ((0, 255, 255), 32), ((255, 128, 0), 14), ((255, 255, 0), 9)],
     [((209, 54, 57), 39025), ((255, 255, 255), 10311), ((226, 130, 132), 204), ((0, 0, 0), 32)]
]

print('--- version 1 ---')

for example in color_list:
    result = []
    for item in example:
        result.append(item[0])
    print(result)
```

Result

```
[(0, 113, 197)]
[(4, 7, 7)]
[(66, 133, 244), (234, 67, 53), (251, 188, 5), (52, 168, 83), (0, 255, 255), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0)]
[(209, 54, 57), (255, 255, 255), (226, 130, 132), (0, 0, 0)]
```

You can also write it as function

```
print('--- version 2 ---')
    
def extract(data):
    result = []
    for item in data:
        result.append(item[0])
    return result

for example in color_list:
    result = extract(example)
    print(result)
```

or shortly as list comprehension

```
print('--- version 3 ---')
        
for example in color_list:
    result = [item[0] for item in example]
    print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example for single image

```
import extcolors

colors, pixels = extcolors.extract_from_path('lenna.png')

rgb_list = [x[0] for x in colors]

print(rgb_list)
```

Comment: You've made a mistake on the brackets of the list.  Its like this: `example = [[(...`

Comment: I copied data from your question - so eventually you make mistake :)

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it. Can you take a look now? How do I apply your logic to that list?

Comment: I test it - in current version I has to only remove `[0]` and it works the same

Comment: When I index 0, I get `[((0, 113, 197), 25727)]`

Comment: See new code - there was `[0]` in two places. I had to remove only in one

Comment: BTW: I found documentation for [extcolor](https://pypi.org/project/extcolors/) and maybe your problem is that it returns two values `colors, pixel_count = extcolors.extract_from_path(...)` but you get both in one variable `colors`

Comment: I added simple example for single image

Comment: This is my current variable. It doesn't make a difference `colors, pixels = extcolors.extract_from_path(logo)`

Comment: do you run my code with `colors` which have values from single image or with `color_list` which have values from many images. It is big difference